# Why do queries run through MyDAC TMyConnection sometimes fail because the connection protocol (IPv4 vs IPv6) changes

Tags: mysql, ipv6, ipv4, devart

**Scenario**

My application obtains the public IP address of the user by running a small PHP script on the same server that hosts my database. I then programatically insert that IP address into the remote hosts table so that I can gain remote access to the DB to run queries etc on port 3306.

When I first get the IP address it may return as IPv4 or IPv6, depending on the whims of the server. I store the IP address I get, test the connection by setting TMyconnection to true - which works OK  and disconnect again. Later,  when I use TMyquery to run a query against the database I reconnect, or let the query do that, and run the query.

*I do have the means to get my IP address as definitely IPv4 so I could standardise on IPv4 and always store that in the remote hosts.*

**The problem**

Assume I have an IPv4 address stored in the remote hosts table (in the form 185.83.68.71) and the test connection passed.
Sometimes, but not always, when the application later runs a query, it gets an error back from the database along the lines of " Connection Error :#28000Access denied for user 'myuser'@'2a0c:5c86:8220:1:8905:f958:d2f8:368d' (using password: YES) i.e. the TMyconnection is now trying to reach the database using my user's  IPv6 IP address. This of course fails as that address is not in the remote hosts.

I have also had the opposite. The application stores an IPv6 address and tests the connection OK but TMyConnection later uses an IPv4 address, which fails as the IPv4 address is not in the remote hosts table.

**Question**

(1) Does TMyconnection itself get the user's IP address from somewhere every time it connects, which might be returned as a different protocol to the one the application obtained? If not how does it know which protocol, IPv4 or IPv6, to use for the connection?

(2) Is there a way to force TMyconnection to always use IPv4? Then my application can always obtain the user's IP address in IPv4 and always store an address that matches the one TMyConnection will use.

*(I have posted a similar question on the Devart forum but that is not very active and there are more talented people here!)*

Comment: Disable v4 or v6 so that you will not have the problem

Comment: Also what is up with the use of the devart tag?  Are you using one of their softwares?  How are they relevant?  Are you using their connector?  But yeah like nbk said just disable the one you don't use and that should limit this from happening.

Comment: @easilyfixed I don't really understand your confusion with the Devart tag. Devart make the TMyConnection component, which my question said I was using. So yes, I am using their software and yes I am using their connector.

Other posts on SO ask specifically about issues with Devart's components such as TMyQuery and TMyConnection and many get answered by knowledgeable people. So I thought including Devart in the tags would alert those SO members that understood Devart's components. Is that wrong in your opinion?

Comment: @nbnk "Disable v4 or v6" - that's exactly what I was asking how to do in question 2. Please can you be more specific? How can I disable IPv6 in the TMyConnection component?

Comment: Have you tried this?: https://docs.devart.com/mydac/devart.mydac.tmyconnectionoptions.ipversion.htm

Comment: Yes but tMyConnection doesn't have a property IPvesion and it isn't clear where the class tMyConnectionOpions is. That's why I asked on SO in the hope that someone here had already done it and could explain where that property is. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my question 2 so I'm putting it here in case others need it. The TMyConnection has a property *Options* and that has a property *IPVersion*. The *IPversion* can be set to the values *ivIPv4*, *ivIPv6* or *ivIPboth*.

But the default is *ivIPv4*, so the TMyConnection used in my application should have only been using an IPv4 response when connecting. So I still don't understand why it sometimes used an IPv6 address and my question 1 remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed that to indicate the IP Version in MyDAC there is a property "IPVersion".
This property can take three values:

- ivIPBoth - specifies that either Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6) or Version 4 (IPv4) will be used;
- ivIPv4 (default) - specifies that Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4) will be used;
- ivIPv6 - specifies that Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6) will be used.

Here is an example of the code to indicate the required protocol version:

...

uses

..., CRVio;

...

MyConnection.Options.IPVersion := ivIPv4;

...

More details about the property can be found in our documentation: https://docs.devart.com/mydac/devart.mydac.tmyconnectionoptions.ipversion.htm